# How to get comment content before it is submitted (WordPress)?

Tags: wordpress, spam-prevention, comments

I want to made a little change for WordPress comment function. That will help me prevent spammers. My idea is:

When comment form is submitted, my function will get the comment content (email, website, content,..) if one of them or all of them are contained some words that in blacklist, the comment will be reject immediately.

Please tell me know the function help me get comment content and where can I put to action.

Thanks so much !

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the hook [comment_post_redirect](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/comment_post_redirect), which is called after the form is posted. There you may wish to verify the comment.

Or you can use the hook comment_post, which runs after saving the comment to DB, but you can still mark it as SPAM.

Comment: Hello, I checked 'comment_post_redirect' however I want to check comment BEFORE it is saved to database. If you have any idea please tell me know ! Thanks so much !